# Can someone resolve the error in this code

Tags: javascript, sql

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select c1.itemname,c1.itemcalorie,p.restname,p.location from categorie1 c1 ,Place p
where p.pincode = '" + pincode1 + "' and c1.itemid IN 
("select c1.itemid from categorie1 c1 where c1.itemcalorie <='" + cal1 + "'  and c1.itemcalorie >='" + cal1-400 + "' and c1.restid = p.restid ") ");
```

Comment: Please make an effort to improve the content and format of your question. Provide some detail and explain what you've tried. Failure to do so will inevitably result in your question being ignored and/or closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you are unsure.

Comment: Your `IN` clause introduces additional quotes but, without seeing the actual error you're receiving back, it's too hard to say.

Comment: If you assembled your query first (somehow) like `query = "select c1.itemname, c1.itemcalorie, p.restname, p.location from categorie1 c1 ,Place p where p.pincode = '" + pincode1 + "' and c1.itemid IN 
("select c1.itemid from categorie1 c1 where c1.itemcalorie <='" + cal1 + "'  and c1.itemcalorie >='" + cal1-400 + "' and c1.restid = p.restid ") ";` to then run it `rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);`, you could in between output your query and check it for being legit…

Answer (score 0):

You have too many extra quotes:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(
"
SELECT c1.itemname, 
       c1.itemcalorie, 
       p.restname, 
       p.location 
FROM   categorie1 c1, 
       place p 
WHERE  p.pincode = '" + pincode1 + "' 
       AND c1.itemid IN (SELECT c1.itemid 
                         FROM   categorie1 c1 
                         WHERE  c1.itemcalorie <= '" + cal1 + "' 
                                AND c1.itemcalorie >= '" + cal1-400 + "' 
                                AND c1.restid = p.restid)
"
);
```

Im not sure wihch language is this (I hope it is not javascript) but the code is not safe look into parametrized query.

Comment: The question _is_ tagged with JavaScript.